Quadratic solution from quartic
I'm struggling to follow the derivation in the steps below, which are copied from a textbook (Agarwal, Foundations of Analog and Digital Circuits). I can't follow the derivation, which is solving (14.42) to get the results of (14.45) and (14.46).
In general I could solve (14.42) by taking the two cases of the +/- separately and then solving the two different quadratics, but this method apparently finds the solutions simultaneously. I'm not sure how to get from (14.42) to (14.43), and I'm also confused on how you "keep track" of how many separate values your final result is supposed to represent when it has multiple +/- as in (14.44).


I agree that perhaps the given answer is a little unclear; it is solving both the quadratics at the same time on (14.44), giving 4 solutions, and I think the fact that it uses $\pm$ in such a manner is a little confusing (because it is difficult to tell that the $\pm$ can be different signs in that line). They could have avoided this quite easily, but my guess is that the author implicitly thought that the reader would understand that there were 4 solutions written there, without realising that it could cause confusion.

This is the kind of ambiguity that frequently occurs with the $\pm$ symbol. You cannot logically infer the exact meaning from the notation alone.

Observe
$
\begin{align}
G = \pm \Big( \omega C - \frac {1}{\omega L} \Big). \quad
& \Longleftrightarrow \quad \omega C - \frac {1}{\omega L} = \pm G. \\
& \Longleftrightarrow \quad \omega - \frac {1}{\omega C L} = \pm \frac {G}{C}. \\
& \Longleftrightarrow \quad {\omega}^{2} - \frac {1}{C L} = \pm \omega \frac {G}{C}. \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad {\omega}^{2} \mp \omega \frac {G}{C} - \frac {1}{C L} = 0.
\end{align} \tag*{}
$

$$\frac{Gw}{C}=\pm(w^2-\frac{1}{LC})\implies w^2-\frac{1}{LC}=\pm \frac{Gw}{C} \leftrightarrow w^2 \pm\frac{Gw}{C}-\frac{1}{LC}=0$$
